# how to visualize pcd file.?

Tags: ros, pcd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
i am trying to read .pcd file and view it through pcl_visualizer.
do i have to write separate code for it or can i directly use some commands??
i tried pcd_viewer filename.pcd also, but its not working.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27483/how-to-visualize-pcd-file.??/) by [youga](https://answers.ros.org/users/1191/youga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2012-02-12

Post score: 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use `pcl_viewer -multiview 1 <pcd_filepath>` to visualize the pcd file.
More info is provided on [PCL Binaries](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/walkthrough.php#binaries)

---

Originally posted by [ShubhamVerma](https://answers.ros.org/users/22795/shubhamverma/) with karma: 146 on 2015-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) on 2017-02-17**:
On Ubuntu you can easily get `pcl_viewer` by installing the `pcl-tools` package.

**Comment by [sant](https://answers.ros.org/users/30592/sant/) on 2017-06-01**:
felix yest!, finaly thats the package i was looking for

**Comment by [Georg Bartels](https://answers.ros.org/users/2542/georg-bartels/) on 2018-07-12**:
Indeed, Felix' comment was very helpful. I was also looking for the name of that package. Thanks!

**Comment by [chillbird](https://answers.ros.org/users/47369/chillbird/) on 2019-12-13**:
thanks Felix!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the pcd_viewer: `rosrun perception_pcl pcd_viewer <filename>`
Starting it without filename will show you options.
You can set the coloring using the number keys.

From ROS Hydro on the viewer is called pcl_viewer and is in /usr/bin, so just calling `pcl_viewer <filename>` should work.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-02-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [youga](https://answers.ros.org/users/1191/youga/) on 2012-02-17**:
i tried above cmd but its saying couldn't find package perception_pcl although it is installed.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-02-19**:
Since there are many reasons why this might fail (is it in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH?), try "locate pcd_viewer" to find it, then start it with the absolute path should solve this for all cases.

**Comment by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on 2013-02-27**:
Try just `$ pcd_viewer filename`, there are some path issues with Groovy: http://answers.ros.org/question/54132/pcl_ros-bag_to_pcd-not-found/

**Comment by [Tones](https://answers.ros.org/users/3551/tones/) on 2013-10-09**:
In ROS hydro, the former pcd_viewer is renamed to pcl_viewer. Therefore try `$ pcl_viewer <filename>`, if you are using hydro.

**Comment by [Sergio MP](https://answers.ros.org/users/542/sergio-mp/) on 2014-10-03**:
@Tones Thank you! pcl_viewer  worked for me on ROS Hydro!

**Comment by [vinayakkgarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/55269/vinayakkgarg/) on 2020-05-26**:
For ROS Kinetic:

1. Install pcl-tools: sudo apt install pcl-tools
2. Run the command: pcl_viewer filename.pcd

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try the following
/opt/ros/fuerte/bin/pcd_viewer path_to_your_file/file_name
example:
/opt/ros/fuerte/bin/pcd_viewer my_map.pcd

If you are using groovy, then
/opt/ros/groovy/bin/pcd_viewer my_map.pcd

---

Originally posted by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) with karma: 693 on 2013-02-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2